# Image uploading Issue using POST method in swift(IOS)

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to upload image and data using `post` method in `swift3` .

**Here is my code  :**

```
 func dataToUpload() {




    let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage.image!, 0.4)! as NSData
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
    let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)


    let param=[
        "Is_checkin" : "0",
        "Description" : self.cookingText.text!,
        "Videolink" : "",
        "Post_image" : base64String ,

        "Created_by" : "4490",
        "Created_on" : "29/Aug/2017" ,


        ] as [String : Any]
    Alamofire.request("https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/insert_post", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response.result.value!)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            break

        }
    }
}
```

**But the image is not uploading .**

Please help to upload

Comment: You can use Alamofire multipartFormData for uploading image.

Comment: what error do you get? Are you sure it is not server related?

Comment: The string is uploading .But not the image

Comment: Previously the string was uploaded .But now it showing some fatal error

Comment: It showing error like                                                                                                     
{
    ExceptionMessage = "A generic error occurred in GDI+.";
    ExceptionType = "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException";
    Message = "An error has occurred.";
    StackTrace = "   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
\n   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)